# Botones de JOptionPane.showInputDialog con texto en español

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber como conseguir que el texto de los botones de un `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` salga en español y no en inglés. A mi me sale, por ejemplo, "Ok" o "Cancel", pero veo por videos, sobre todo en youtube, que a mucha gente le sale "Aceptar" y "Cancelar". He intentado buscarlo por internet, pero no he encontrado la solución. Estoy usando Eclipse 2022-12 con Java 17. Gracias.

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: Hola, pues intente añadir un array de botones con setOptions de la clase JOptionPane creando un objeto JOPtionPane.  Ejemplo (se que es una chapuza, pero por probar):                                                                                       JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
JButton ok = new JButton("Sí");
JButton cancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");
pane.setOptions(new JButton[] {ok, cancelar});
String res = pane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduzca opción", "Título", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);     
No funcionó.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les sale aceptar y cancelar porque eso depende del idioma en que esté configurado el equipo, yo por ejemplo lo tengo en inglés y me sale Ok y Cancel.

Pero si quieres personalizar puedes usar este código

```
int seleccion = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
    null,
    "Seleccione opcion",
    "Selector de opciones",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    null,
    new Object[] { "Aceptar", "Cancelar" },
    null);
```

Para imprimir el valor de la selección puedes usar esto (el valor de aceptar es 0 y el valor de cancelar es 1)

```
if (seleccion != -1)
  System.out.println("seleccionada opcion " + (seleccion + 1));
```

Otra opción sería modificar el texto de los tipos de botones usando el siguiente código.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane
import javax.swing.UIManager

UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "Cancelar") // texto para cancel es Cancelar
UIManager.put("OptionPane.okButtonText", "Aceptar") // texto para ok es Aceptar
String seleccion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    null,
    "Input dialog",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); 

System.out.println("El usuario ha escrito "+seleccion);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Funciona muy bien con las segunda opción que me has dado. Un gran saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que es porque Java basa el idioma a partir de la configuracion de idioma y ubicacion regional del sistema operativo.

Sin embargo está a disposicion la clase [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) que permite cambiar cierta configuracion cuando sea necesario.
Si necesitas saber concretamente que idioma esta usando la `JVM` puedes usar `Locale.getDefault()`, en mi caso me devuelve `en_CO` (*en efecto mi SO en ingles y region Colombia*).

Ahora, puedes intentar usar `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("es","ES"));` antes de usar cualquier componente *swing*.

O en la otra mano tambien es posible cambiar la propiedad `user.language` antes de que la *JVM* arranque, ésto por linea de comandos:

`java -Duser.language=es MiAplicacion`

Aqui hay una lista de [Supported Locales](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk17-suported-locales.html) por si resulta necesario consultar otro a conveniencia.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la información. En mi caso, Locale.getDefaults ya me devuelvía "es_ES". Con la solución del amigo FrEqDe ya conseguí solucionarlo. De todas formas, muchas gracias por el esfuerzo. Saludos.